# Цвет строки заголовка

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

Как в uwp программно изменить цвет строки заголовка?

[image: картинка]

Спасибо.

Comment: [Статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/310326/). Теперь всегда делаю кастомные заголовки.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

...

var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.TitleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.DarkGreen;
```

Другие возможности по кастомизации цвета [тут](https://stenobot.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/uwp-app-development-styling-the-desktop-title-bar/).